# Why is my program not outputting the right count of words?

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct thread_data {
  FILE *fp;
  long int offset;
  int start;
  int blockSize;
  //struct word maybe?
};

int words = 0;

void *countFrequency(void* data) {
  struct thread_data* td = data;
  char *buffer = malloc(td->blockSize);

  int i, c;
  i = 0; c = 0;
  enum states { WHITESPACE, WORD };
  int state = WHITESPACE;

  fseek(td->fp, td->offset, td->start);

  char last = ' ';
  while ((fread(buffer, td->blockSize, 1, td->fp)) == 1) {
    if (buffer[0]== ' ' || buffer[0] == '\t') {
      state = WHITESPACE;
    } else if (buffer[0] == '\n') {
      //newLine++;
      state = WHITESPACE;
    } else {
      if (state == WHITESPACE) {
        words++;
      }
      state = WORD;
    }
    last = buffer[0];
  }

  free(buffer);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int nthreads, x, id, blockSize, len;
  //void *state;
  FILE *fp;
  pthread_t *threads;

  fp = fopen("file1.txt", "r");

  printf("Enter the number of threads: ");
  scanf("%d", &nthreads);
  struct thread_data data[nthreads];
  threads = malloc(nthreads * sizeof(pthread_t));

  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  len = ftell(fp);
  printf("len= %d\n", len);

  blockSize = (len + nthreads - 1) / nthreads;
  printf("size= %d\n", blockSize);

  for (id = 0; id < nthreads; id++) {
    data[id].fp = fp;
    data[id].offset = blockSize;
    data[id].start = id * blockSize + 1;
    //maybe data[id]. word struct
  }
  //LAST THREAD
  data[nthreads-1].start=(nthreads-1)*blockSize+1;

  for (id = 0; id < nthreads; id++)
    pthread_create(&threads[id], NULL, &countFrequency,&data[id]);

  for (id = 0; id < nthreads; id++)
    pthread_join(threads[id],NULL);

  fclose(fp);

  printf("%d\n",words);
  return 0;
}
```

I had a segmentation fault that I fixed in this program but now when I run it, I get 0 words, which is incorrect because there are about a million words in the text file.

Can anyone tell me why it is giving me an incorrect word count?

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have is you are using the same file descriptor in each of the `countFrequency` threads, each thread performs an `fseek` once, and then attempts to loop reading.  The last `fseek` wins.

This design flaw must be addressed first.

Comment: @jgabb Your fseek in countFrequency() is incorrect... look at the man page for its third argument.

Comment: As for the file descriptor in countFrequency, should it not be using the same file descriptor since it is pointing to the same file?

Comment: @jgabb Picture this, 3 threads... the first one starts at offset 1, the 2nd one starts at offset 3001, the 3rd starts at offset 6001.  Each are to read 3000 bytes.  Thread one does an fseek() to offset 1, but before it can read thread 2 takes over.  It then does a fseek() to offset 3001, but before it can read, thread 3 takes over.  Thread 3 fseek() to 6001... Now thread one gets control again and it THINKS it is at offset 1, when in reality it is at offset 6001... do you see the problem... you need to either synchronize access, or read the entire file into memory and process it that way.

Comment: In other words you were thinking of the file descriptor as a "per thread" resource, when in reality it is a "per process" resource.

Comment: Ahh I was under the impression that every thread would have its "own" instance of fseek (if that makes any sense, I couldn't figure out how to word it) and that it would not affect it at all.  I can't read the entire file into memory bc it will supposedly be a huge file (>2GB) so I am trying to read it in with parts.  I guess I could set up a mutex lock. Would that work?

Comment: You could pass the name of the file, instead of a file descriptor, and let each thread open the file... which would give each thread its own file descriptor.  So, there would be (in the example above) be three open file descriptors on the same file... each thread seeking and reading in a different section of the file.

Comment: so basically, I should pass data[id].fp = fopen("file1","r")?  That would open a file for each of them.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that the 'fopen()' occur in each thread... so, instead of "struct thread_data" containing a "FILE *fp", it should contain a "char *filename", which each thread would use in their "fopen()" call.